# change image name to permalinks in wordpress automatically

Tags: wordpress, image

How can I change image name to permalinks on wordpress automatically during post?

For example:
this is my permalink

> www.site.com/google-seo/

I want Name's of image in post be this:

> google-seo.jpg
>   google-seo-1.jpg
>   google-seo-2.jpg

I use this hack for custom image name:

```html
function make_custom_filename($filename) {
        $info = pathinfo($filename);
$custom_filename = "custom image name";
        $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
        $name = basename($custom_filename, $ext);
        return $name . $ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_custom_filename', 100);
```

How can I change this for change name to second part of permalinks ?